# type safe programming languages..?

Tags: java, c++, c, programming-languages

Could people please rank some programming languages like C,C++,Java,perl etc on benchmark line of type-safe,not-type-safe,weak-typed,strong-typed,static-typed,dynamic-typed,strict-typed etc. Also, if these terms overlap, please let me know.

Comment: Uhm ... no? I don't think SO is the right place for this kind of open-ended question.

Comment: okay, I will wait for the question to be closed. Already 2 votes in. The section "Type safety issues in specific languages" of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety does address this question to some extent. Java is missing though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages#Type_systems